# Update a matrix through advanced indexing/vectorizing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a matrix of what is effectively counters.  I would like to increment those counters based on a list of column indices - with each positional index also corresponding to a row increment.

This is straightforward with a for loop, and a little less straightforward with list comprehension.  In either case, iteration is involved.  But I was wondering if there is any way to vectorise this problem?

The minimal problem is:

```
counters = np.zeros((4,4))
counters
array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])


update_columns = [1,0,2,2]

for row, col in zip(range(len(update_columns)), update_columns):
    counters[row, col] += 1
    
counters
array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called advanced numpy indexing. You can pass the row index using `np.arange` and column index using `update_columns`:

```
update_columns = np.array(update_columns)
counters[np.arange(update_columns.size), update_columns] += 1
```

output:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0.]]
```